# Algorithm: Given an array, find the maximum sum after rearrangement

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

You are given an array A, of size N, containing numbers from 0-N. For each sub-array starting from 0th index, lets say Si, we say Bi is the smallest non negative number that is not present in Si.

We need to find the maximum possible sum of all Bi of this array.

We can rearrange the array to obtain the maximum sum.

For example:

A = 1, 2, 0 , N = 3

then lets say we rearranged it as A= 0, 1, 2

S1 = 0,  B1= 1

S2 = 0,1 B2= 2

S3 = 0,1,2  B3= 3

Hence the sum is 6

Whatever examples I have tried, I have seen that sorted array will give the maximum sum. Am I correct or missing something here.

Please help to find the correct logic for this problem. I am not looking for optimal solution but just the correct logic.

Comment: Yes, sorting the array maximizes the sum of Bᵢ

Comment: You are right, when you take a subarray as you defined you'd want the remaining array to contain greater elements than those in subarray to maximize, when you need that at every index you need a sorted array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, sorting the array maximizes the sum of

As the input size is , it does not include every number in the range {0, ..., }, as that is a set of  + 1 numbers. Let's say it only lacks value , then  is  for all  >= . If there are other numbers that are missing, but greater than , there is no impact on any .

Thus we need to find out the minimum missing value  in the range {0, ..., }. And then the maximised sum is 1 + 2 + ... +  + (−). This is (+1)/2 + (−) = (1 + 2 − )/2

To find the value of , create a boolean array of size  + 1, and set the entry at index  to true when  is encountered in the input.  is then the first index at which that boolean array still has a false value.

Here is a little implementation in a JavaScript snippet:

```js
function maxSum(arr) {
   const n = arr.length;
   const isUsed = Array(n + 1).fill(false);
   for (const value of arr) {
       isUsed[value] = true;
   }
   const k = isUsed.indexOf(false);
   return k * (1 + 2*n - k) / 2;
}

console.log(maxSum([0, 1, 2])); // 6
console.log(maxSum([0, 2, 2])); // 3
console.log(maxSum([1, 0, 1])); // 5
```

Comment: OP says array containing numbers from 0 to N not necessarily contiguous. If the input is like 1, 3, 0, this won't work or even when items are duplicated like 2, 0, 2 it won't work. It has to be sorted.

Comment: @SomeDude correct. The question does not say all numbers are contiguous. Just the values are not greater than N

Comment: Ah, I see. I have rewritten my answer.